# how to put a vertical line in sudoku table

Tags: css

im try to get vrticl line Under the arrow.

for the horizental line i used .

```
     webkit-box-shadow: 0px 3px 0px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.99);
     -moz-box-shadow: 0px 3px 0px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.99);
     box-shadow: 0px 3px 0px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.99);
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you're specifically wanting to use box-shadow, you can use the first property in the box-shadow shorthand, which adjusts the horizontal offset:

```
webkit-box-shadow: 3px 3px 0px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.99);
-moz-box-shadow: 3px 3px 0px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.99); 
box-shadow: 3px 3px 0px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.99);
```

But given you're not using box-shadow to get a shadow effect (i.e. not using blur or spread), a border might be preferable, as it'll give you the same divider look you're after, but will be repositioned if you adjust the padding between your cells. You can do away with your browser prefixes too:

```
border-right: 3px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.99);
border-bottom: 3px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.99);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `box-shadow: 5px 0 2px -2px rgba(0,0,0,0.99);`

This sets the X offset more to the right.